# How firebase phone number authentication verifies phone number with the otp sent without giving permission to read sms?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

im just wondering , how fierebase can verify a phone number in my flutter project by signing in when the otp is recieved without giving access to read SMS from users phone ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any extra permission on Android to read the SMS if you or the external package that you are using is making use of [SMS Retriever API](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/overview).

On iOS, SMS auto fill is provided by default.